# IIS Manager on Windows SERVER 2012

Tags: azure, iis, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows Server 2008 when a user Open **Server manager** the user can browse the **IIS Manager** like this --

[image]

And the user can see the server and do other stuff.

Now on Windows Server 2012 the IIS Manager can not be found in the same maner i belive, i need to be found by opening **Server Manager** and than select **IIS Manager**, like this --

[image]

Now the problem is when i open the IIS Manager i can not see my server name and it looks like this ---

[image]

I have also check on Add Roles that the IIS Manager is installed ---

[image]

Any one have any idea why i can not see my server name on the IIS Manager on **Windows Server 2012**

Comment: First it is a new design of Server Manager so you have to get used to it. Second, the Connections panel in IIS Manager has a toolbar where you can add IIS servers via menu items.

Answer (score 0):

What roles/features of IIS are installed on the 2012 server? If IIS is installed correctly, IIS Manager should show the same layout/options on 2012 as you see on 2008.